# Sharepoint: How to update a ListItem field which is Lookup multiple values using Sharepoint RestAPI?

Tags: jquery, rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

## Sharepoint: How to update a ListItem field which is Lookup multiple values using Sharepoint RestAPI?

I want to update a ListItem field, this field type is Lookup multiple value. I code the sample test but it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
 function UpdateItemLookup() {
    // Getting our list items
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('testlist')/Items(1)",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        cache: true,
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            Update(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}

function Update(result) {
    $.ajax({          
        url: result.d.__metadata.uri,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        body: JSON.stringify({
            "__metadata": { type: "SP.Data.Test_x0020_listListItem" },
            Title: "bbbb",
            lookup1: [1, 3] //the lookup field needs to be updated to "1" and "3" 
        }),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
            "If-Match": result.d.__metadata.etag
        },
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
```

I get this error:

```
"{"error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"A node of type 'EndOfInput' was read from the JSON reader when trying to read the start of an entry. A 'StartObject' node was expected."}}}"
```

The lookupfield internalname is correct.
[image]

Error:
[image]

Anyone here can solve my problem? Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally find the error. The field name is correct "lookup1", but when I update the value of this field, I need to add postfix "Id" after the field name. My case should be "lookup1Id' and it works.

```
 function Update(result) {
    var item = $.extend({
        "__metadata": { "type": "SP.Data.Test_x0020_listListItem" }
    }, {
        Title: "test item aaaa",
        lookup1Id: { "results": [1, 3] }, //here is the problem, it should be "lookup1Id"
    });

    $.ajax({            
        url: result.d.__metadata.uri,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        data: JSON.stringify(item),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
            "If-Match": result.d.__metadata.etag
        },
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is some issue when you are trying to post data. It could be related to json stringify.

Please try the below updated code for `Update` method:

```
function Update(result) {

    var itemMetadata = {
        "__metadata": { "type": "SP.Data.Test_x0020_listListItem" }, 
        "Title": "bbbb",
        "lookup1": {"results": [1,3] }
    }; 

    $.ajax({          
        url: result.d.__metadata.uri,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        data: JSON.stringify(itemMetadata),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),            
            "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
            "If-Match": "*"
        },
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work, shows the same error. I just realise that when I update only the Title with the value "bbbb", it works. But when I also update field lookup, it fails :( @Gautam

Comment: Are you using the correct internal name ? Also, check if the `"SP.Data.Test_x0020_listListItem` is correct. Other than that, code is correct.

Comment: Yes I'm sure that the lookupfield caused the error. When I remove the lookup field, I only update the Title, it works perfectly. The property list.EntityTypeName is "Test_x0020_listList"

Comment: ok, go to your sharepoint list > settings page. Check the internal name of the lookup column. After that, use that name in the code. It should work

Comment: Yes, it's correct. Please have a look at the image attached. I updated the question by adding an image. @Gautam

Comment: can you replace `lookup1: [1, 3]` to `lookup1: 1` and check ?

Comment: Damn it, I finally find the error. The field name is correct "lookup1", but when I update the value of this field, I need to add postfix "Id" after the field name. My case should be "lookup1Id' and it works. Thanks @Gautam anyway.